# Varchar in sql creating extra whitespaces

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

Well, I am building a small hobby program in C#, and I am trying to write information from my program to Sql

The thing is I have some `varchar` fields in Sql with a max length of 50
when I send information to fill those columns they will be added with extra space until reaching 50 chars

I already tried to change `varchar` to `nvarchar` just to see if it works

What I have been researching is that `nchar` does this kind of thing but with `varchar` I shouldn't have problem but I am having them..

```
public PersonModel CreatePerson(PersonModel model)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection =
        new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString(db)))
    {
        var p = new DynamicParameters();
        p.Add("@FirstName", model.FirstName);
        p.Add("@LastName", model.LastName);
        p.Add("@EmailAddress", model.EmailAddress);
        p.Add("@CellphoneNumber", model.CellphoneNumber);
        p.Add("@id", 0, dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

        connection.Execute("dbo.spPeople_Insert", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        model.Id = p.Get<int>("@id");

        return model;
    }
}
```

and here is how i call it

```
    if (ValidateForm())
    {
        PersonModel p = new PersonModel();
        p.FirstName = firstNameValue.Text;
        p.LastName = lastNameValue.Text;
        p.EmailAddress = emailValue.Text;
        p.CellphoneNumber = cellphoneValue.Text;
```

those are textbox in my form btw

Comment: call `Trim()` on you `string` values before sending them to the SQL database.

Comment: they are been passed without spaces because im checking with the debuggin

Comment: How do you check if the column value has extra spaces?

Comment: ltrim and rtrim functions in sql

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya first if i copy the column value to clipboard and paste it it has the spaces and in my program i seen them with space aswell

Comment: @maSTAShuFu i would like to know why its been adding space instead of adding a trim

Comment: Can you share the code which saves data to the database? Also, I am sure you have done this but I would suggest to recheck the data Type of the column

Comment: @AlejandroSánchez sql is bound to use scalar data types.. you need to specify the size of the data, thus ltrim or rtrim should be applied

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i updated my post check it out

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql) 
You need to set `SET ANSI_PADDING  OFF`
please note that existing columns will not be be affected by changing the setting only new ones

Comment: if i have to set ansi_padding off, then whats the diference between nchar and varchar?

Comment: if you mean the difference between char and varchar here is an article explain how it works under different setting  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlstudies/2017/06/15/turning-ansi_padding-off-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Answer (score 1):

Few things you can check actually

check the stored procedure parameters to ensure they are also nvarchar as your column types are in nvarchar

and as Cyber Progs states check the ANSI_PADDING

```
SET ANSI_PADDING  OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Use trim in your code while passing data to database.

For eg: p.Add("@FirstName", model.FirstName.Trim());

Comment: TRIM! is not use for convert varchar to nvarchar. please read how to add good answer for give best feedback in stack overflow link: https://stackoverflow.com/help